# How can i create horizontal scroll card in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to create horizontal scroll cards with indicators and only one card in the screen ?

[image]

Comment: can you include card code?

Comment: what would the indicator do? How are you going to change it?

Comment: @eamirho3ein Sorry. I don't have card code for it.

Comment: @RisheekMittal like carousel slider

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [banner_carousel](https://pub.dev/packages/banner_carousel). I think it best suits your need. Try the `customizedBanner` property to get your card for a carousel slide :

```
BannerCarousel(
   animation: false,
   viewportFraction: 0.60,
   showIndicator: false,
   customizedBanners: [
        Container(
           decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black,width: 2),),
              child: Image.network(BannerImages.banner1)),
        Container(
             margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  boxShadow: [
                     BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25),
                        spreadRadius: 0,
                        blurRadius: 4,
                        offset: Offset(0, 3),
                      ),
                    ],
               ),
              child: Image.network(BannerImages.banner2)),
         Container(
             margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
             decoration: BoxDecoration(
             border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    width: 3,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/widgets/owl-2.jpg'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
           ),
       ),
    ],
),
```